# How to download only a working directory of the AOSP source code without the entire repo history?

Tags: android, git, android-source

The size of the latest AOSP source code is rather large (around 30-35 Gb for the .repo directory and another 15 Gb or so for the working directory). Is there a way to download only a snapshot of the latest version of the source code (official marshmallow release) without the entire repo history? That would save me a lot in bandwidth and storage.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can specify `--depth 1` to [git clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) command. It will only get the latest snapshot.

Comment: Thank you, this works great when using git on individual projects. It looks like to apply the depth for all projects within AOSP all at once, it can be done with the following repo command: `repo init --depth=1 -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-6.0.0_r1` prior to running `repo sync`

Comment: When using the commands from my comment above, I ended up with a 6.1 Gb .repo directory for the marshmallow branch.

Comment: Can I download the older commits later?

Comment: I downloaded it and it took about 2 hours to download (16mbs)

Comment: I also want to know how to download the commits history later if needed

Answer (score 1):

Since `git` version 2.19 (released in 2018), we can utilize `git`'s `--partial-clone` flag via the `repo` tool like the following:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b master --partial-clone --clone-filter=blob:limit=10M
```

For readers of this question and answer in 2020, be warned that the AOSP repositories have gotten bigger and the above command still results in around 73 gigabytes of source code and related files.

Answer (score 0):

Step to download android source code(AOSP) in Ubuntu

1. First create one folder like "**aosp-m**" to copy AOSP code in your machine.
2. Open terminal(Ctrl+Alt+T) and change your Dir to latest created Dir let say "**aosp-m**"
3. After that Run the following command in terminal :- 
   ***git clone git://gitz01/cm/download/android/manifest***
   if this link not work then try this one
   repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
4. Run Following command in terminal one by one
   ***git config --global user.name "Your Name"
   git config --global user.email "you@example.com"***
5. then run following command for repo init
   ***repo init -u git://gitz01/cm/download/android/manifest -b master -m identifiedmanifest.xml***
   if this link not work then try this one
   repo init --depth=1 -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b identifiedmanifest.xml
   here you can replace **identifiedmanifest.xml** to your desired AOSP source code , Let Say "**android-6.0.1_r10.xml**" marshmellow.
6. and in the last run "***repo sync***" command. This command start downloading your desired  AOSP code in your machine. This opertation take more than 1 hours(depending on your internet connection speed) to download source code. 
   Thats it... Happy Coding.......

Comment: what is **git://gitz01**?

Comment: "git://gitz01" repo link of AOSP. Your company SCM Team manage it